# Reading multiple values from the same input line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, distance

I am trying to write a program that calculates the distance between two points from standard input. But the two points must be read from the same line.
For example (25,2) (26,15). I am stuck on a part where I could not put those inputs on one line.
I have this so far:

```
/*
This Distance Program calculates the distance between two points
 */
package distance;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Distance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("X1");

        try {

            double x1 = input.nextDouble();

            double y1 = input.nextDouble();

            double x2 = input.nextDouble();

            double y2 = input.nextDouble();

            double dist = Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)));
            System.out.println("Distance between two points is: " + dist);
        } catch (Exception E) {
            System.out.println(E);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Read as a string and then extract number from that.

Comment: use [Scanner#nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) and parse the input according to your format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GhostCat pointed out, you could use [regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to check user input format. I implemented one possible solution.

1. Ask user input in (x1,y1) (x2,y2) format.
2. Check if the user input is correct (Print error message if it is not).
3. If the format is correct you do the maths: Calculate the distance using matcher [groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) to get the subsequence captured.

### Raw Regex:

> ^((-?\d+),(-?\d+))\s((-?\d+),(-?\d+))$

The regex will match parenthesis, comas, and spaces literally, and it will catch in groups the four numbers. i.e.

[image: Regex example]

### Distance Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Distance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Insert two point to calculate the distance. Format: (x1,y1) (x2,y2) : ");

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\)\\s\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\)$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( input.nextLine ( ) );

        if ( matcher.matches ( ) )
        {
            System.out.println ( "Good" );
            double dist = Math.sqrt( Math.pow ( Long.parseLong ( matcher.group(3) ) - Long.parseLong ( matcher.group(1) ) , 2 ) + 
                    Math.pow ( Long.parseLong ( matcher.group(4) ) - Long.parseLong ( matcher.group(2) ) , 2 ) );
            System.out.println ( "Distance: " + dist );
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println ( "Wrong input format" );
        }

    }

}
```

**Note:** Since you are using the [Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) Class i recommend use [pow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) instead raw multiplication.

**Note2:** In java a character preceded by a backslash (\) is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler. That's why in the code you have to append an extra one.

### I/O Examples:

```
Insert two point to calculate the distance. Format: (x1,y1) (x2,y2) : 
2 3 4 5
Wrong input format

Insert two point to calculate the distance. Format: (x1,y1) (x2,y2) : 
(-2,-3) (-4,4)
Good
Distance: 7.280109889280518
```

### Extra:

You could also verify for points range. It's more clear if you create an static method like this.

```
public static boolean rangeInclusive(int x, int y, int min, int max)
    {
        return x>=min && x<=max && y>=min && y<=max;    
    }
```

> This will return true if x and y are in the min-max range inclusive. False otherwise.

Said that you do the maths only if the points are in the range, like this:

```
if ( matcher.matches ( ) )
        {
            if( rangeInclusive ( Integer.parseInt ( matcher.group(1) ) , Integer.parseInt ( matcher.group(2) ), -50 , 50 ) &&
                    rangeInclusive ( Integer.parseInt ( matcher.group(3) ) , Integer.parseInt ( matcher.group(4) ), -50 , 50 ))
            {
                double dist = Math.sqrt( Math.pow ( Long.parseLong ( matcher.group(3) ) - Long.parseLong ( matcher.group(1) ) , 2 ) + 
                        Math.pow ( Long.parseLong ( matcher.group(4) ) - Long.parseLong ( matcher.group(2) ) , 2 ) );
                System.out.println ( "Distance: " + dist );
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println ( "Wrong range" );
            }

        }
```

Comment: Nice one. I stayed away from putting up a regex example to not overburden our newbie programmer; but your solution takes the time required to introduce this topic. I would upvote twice if i could. Haha, actually I can. Well, do something having the similar effect ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I am not very familiar with regular expressions but your explanation made it very clear to understand. But  if i need to set up a limit for an example, the points must be between -50 to 50, how do I do it?

Comment: It's not easy to check for ranges on regex, you need to do it manually. But you can easily verify that on the groups taken (`matcher.group(1)` for example) and return an error if  your range is not correct.

Comment: @UsNepalPlatform I added range verification to the answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

If the format of the input is `##.## ##.## ##.## ##.##` (each `##.##` is a double, and it doesn't need to have a decimal place, e.g. it can be a whole number, such as 5), which means the numbers are separated by spaces, then this will work:

```
String line = input.nextLine();
String[] points = line.split("\\s+");

if(points.length() == 4){
    double x1 = Double.parseDouble(points[0]);
    double y1 = Double.parseDouble(points[1]);
    double x2 = Double.parseDouble(points[2]);
    double y2 = Double.parseDouble(points[3]);
    //and the rest is the same
}
```

What this does, is it reads a `String` from the input. Then it splits that strings by the spaces between them (`\\s+` splits the string into strings that have one or more spaces between them). The array of strings are actually doubles, so we convert them to doubles.

NOTE: If the input is something which isn't a double, you'll get an error.

Comment: Be precise about your wording. "5" can be seen as int; not as double, and it would work ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat I specifically gave 5 as an example :P

Comment: Things are better now.

Answer (score 2):

The **key** thing here is: you have to be **specific** about the exact format that your user should provide. Yes, entering a single string and *parsing* that content is a good idea, but ...you put up this example `(25,2) (26,15)` in your question. And that string will **not** work with Itamars solution.

So the point is: before you start thinking "how do I parse the user input", you have to clarify for **yourself** how you expect/want the user to enter those two coordinates to you.

Meaning: if your user gives you "n1 n2 n3 n4" (so 4 numbers); you can split using \s+. If your user gives you "n1,n2,n3,n4)" then you should split on "," for example.

And to allow for your given format "(x1,y1) (x2,y2)" you would probably first split on \s+ (giving you two strings; which you then split again using ",". Or you learn about regular expressions, because they make **such** parsing much easier to write down.

Long story short: do not work on **unclear** requirements.

Finally: also be precise about **types** used. You are using **double** in your code; but is that really what you need? As your input example ... is using whole numbers only. Of course, double will always work; but when you want your user to use whole numbers, you should be using int or long instead!

Comment: Oh wow I actually forgot about the bit about the format o.o. Thank you so much

Comment: @ItamarGreen And just for the record ... if you found my answer at least helpful ... did you omit the upvote on purpose?

Comment: not at all, just forgetful. One of my numerous flaws

Comment: Nobody is flawed. Dont ever think about you this way. Just keep reminding yourself in positive language what you **want** to do. Like in "upvote each great answer by Ghostcat whenever I spot one" (which is particularly easy, as all my input is great ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat I believe he is using doubles because sqrt method requires it.

Comment: @Thrasher It is fine to pass int values to a method that wants a double. The other direction not so much ;-)